# iOS in app purhcase and wordpress integration

Tags: ios, wordpress, in-app-purchase

Is there a way to integrate iOS in app purchases with the wordpress user system? I just want to set up an in app purchase so that whenever anyone buys using it, a new user with a certain role is created on wordpress.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement client-server communication inside your mobile app. Your app must send an http request to wordpress api when you receive the confirmation that in-app transaction is committed (try to learn it [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_APIs)) and 'ask' it to create new user.

PS. As I understand from wpApi manual there is no method to create users, so you probably will have to implement it yourself)
As you can see the task is not trivial but it's definitely implementable.
Good luck)

Comment: thanks, i actually want to use integrate it with s2member membership plugin for wordpress. basically it will be a lifetime membership so simply creating a user with a certain role as defined in s2member would do.

I came across this plugin after your mention of wp api. do you think it can help? https://wordpress.org/plugins/extended-xml-rpc-api/